# Infix to postfix conversion and evaluation including whitespaces and double quotes

Tags: c

I have the code below, but I need the code to account for white spaces and double digits, for example if i enter (7-3)/(2+2) it should come out 73-22+/ result: 1. If i enter (7 - 3) / (2 + 2) it should come out 7 3 - 2 2 + / result 1. If I enter (22 - 10)/(2 + 2) it should come out 22 10 - 2 2 + / Result: 3

Here is the code I have:

```
#include<stdio.h>
char stack[100];
int top = 0;
int eval_top = -1;
int eval_stack[100];

void push(char x) // Push char into stack
{
  stack[top++] = x;
}
char pop() // Pop char to top of stack
{
  if (top == -1)
    return -1;
  else
    return stack[top--];
}

/* functions for evaluation of postfix expression */
// push function
void eval_push(int x) { // Find push result
  eval_stack[++eval_top] = x;
}
// pop function
int eval_pop() { // Find pop result
  if (eval_top == -1) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return eval_stack[eval_top--];
  }
}

int priority(char x) // check priority order
{
  if (x == '(')
    return 0;
  if (x == '+' || x == '-')
    return 1;
  if (x == '*' || x == '/')
    return 2;
}
// function to evaluate the postfix expression
void EvalPostfix(char postfix[]) {

  int A, B;
  int val;
  char ch;
  int i;

  //find postfix
  for (i = 0; postfix[i] != ')'; i++) {
    ch = postfix[i];
    if (isdigit(ch)) {
      eval_push(ch - '0');
    } else if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/') {

      A = eval_pop();
      B = eval_pop();

      switch (ch) {
      case '*':
        val = B * A;
        break;

      case '/':
        val = B / A;
        break;

      case '+':
        val = B + A;
        break;

      case '-':
        val = B - A;
        break;
      }

      eval_push(val); //send value on top of stack
    }
  }
  printf("\n Result: %d \n", eval_pop());
}

main() {
  int i = 0;
  char * e, x;
  char postfix[100]; // store postfix for later evaluation
  char exp[100];
  printf("Infix expression : ");
  scanf("%s", exp); // asking the user to enter the infix expression
  printf("Postfix expression: ");
  e = exp;
  while ( * e != '\0') {
    if (isalnum( * e)) { // if character is alphabet or number , it is printed
      printf("%c", * e);
      postfix[i++] = * e;
    } else if ( * e == '(') // if it is open parenthesis, it is pushed into the stack without any priority
      push( * e);
    else if ( * e == ')') // if it is closed parenthesis , pop the elements in the stack and print them until the we see ( symbol
    {
      while ((x = pop()) != '(') {
        printf("%c", x);
        postfix[i++] = x;
      }
    } else // if character is symbol like +, -, *, / then based on their priority character is pushed if it high priority otherwise high priority symbols are popped and it is pushed
    {
      while (priority(stack[top]) >= priority( * e)) {
        x = pop();
        printf("%c", x);
        postfix[i++] = x;
      }
      push( * e);
    }
    e++;
  }
  while (top != -1) // printing remaining elements in the stack
  {
    x = pop();
    printf("%c", x);
    postfix[i++] = x;
  }
  postfix[i] = ')'; // this is to add at the end for detecting end by the evaluation function
  EvalPostfix(postfix);
}
```

Comment: [google.com/...](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-set-4-evaluation-postfix-expression/)

Comment: Why do you need to account for spaces for postfix expressions

Comment: It's a part of my assignment

Comment: scanf() stops reading a string at the first space. So, change scanf() for something like fgets(). This will get you closer to a working program. I assume you have a debugger that you can use for stepping through program. Use it, and examine the content of your variables to check that they have their expected values. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code

your *pop* is not symmetric with your *push*, *push* post increment the index so *pop* must pre decrement the index, and because of that the first invalid index is not -1 but 0 :

```
char pop() // Pop char to top of stack
{
  if (top == 0)
    return -1;
  else
    return stack[--top];
}
```

*priority* does not return a value if all the tests are false, but probably the last test is useless

In

> ```
> while (priority(stack[top]) >= priority( * e))
> ```

you missed to check if the stack is empty, must be :

```
while ((top != 0) && (priority(stack[top]) >= priority( * e))) {
```

Because the first invalid index for *stack* is 0 rather than -1

> while (top != -1) // printing remaining elements in the stack

must be

```
while (top != 0) // printing remaining elements in the stack
```

When you make the postfix expression there is no separation between the numbers, for instance "12+3" becomes "123+" like "1+23", and in *EvalPostfix* you consider a number has only one digit (`eval_push(ch - '0');`), so you do not manage the numbers having more than 1 digit. To manage several digits add a separator after all numbers, for instance a space to have "12 3 +" or "1 23 +" and read the number with *scanf* etc

You do not make the right postfix expression in all the cases, for instance for 1+2*3 you make 12+3* but it must be 123*+

You do not detect the invalid infix expressions

---

in

> ```
> while (priority(stack[top]) >= priority( * e))
> ```

I missed to say the top element is not `stack[top]` but `stack[top - 1]` so it must be replaced by

```
while ((top != 0) && (priority(stack[top - 1]) >= priority( * e))) {
```

adding that correction 1+2*3 produces the right postfix expression 123*+

Note it is more clear to introduce the function *empty()* and *tops()*, and in case of an invalid access into the stack print a message and exit rather than to return -1 as a *char*

```
int empty()
{
   return (top == 0);
}

char tops()
{
   if (top == 0) {
     fputs("top() on the empty stack, abort", stderr);
     exit(-1);
   }
   return stack[top - 1];
}

char pop() // Pop char to top of stack
{
  if (top == 0) {
     fputs("pop() on the empty stack, abort", stderr);
     exit(-1);
  }
  return stack[--top];
}
```

also detect a possible overflow of the stack :

```
void push(char x) // Push char into stack
{
  if (top == sizeof(stack)) {
    fputs("stack overflow", stderr);
    exit(-1);
  }
  stack[top++] = x;
}
```

so now you can do

```
    while (!empty() && (priority(tops()) >= priority( * e))) {
```

Of course this is the same for the other stack

> I need the code to account for white spaces and double digits

double digits is too restrictive, just manage any integer, for that you can extract the number using *strtol*. You cannot also read the full expression using `scanf("%s", exp);` because is stops on the first space, use *fgets*.