# Getting segmentation fault while trying to access pointer in for loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a command line calculator, and am encountering a problem in a function I have written to split up a string into several smaller strings of numbers and operators.

This is the function (main is only meant to test it).

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAXNUMLEN 100

void splitter(char *str, char splitted[][MAXNUMLEN]) {
    int next_op = 0;
    int last_op = 0;
    int next_free = 0;
    while(strlen(str) - last_op > 1) {
        for(next_op; 
               *(str+next_op) != '+' 
            && *(str+next_op) != '-' 
            && *(str+next_op) != '*' 
            && *(str+next_op) != '/';
            ++next_op)
            ;

        for(int i = last_op; i < next_op; ++i)
            splitted[next_free][i] = *(str+i);

        splitted[next_free][next_op] = '\0';
        ++next_free;
        last_op = next_op;
        ++next_op;
    }
}

int main() {
    char temp[] = "1+1";
    char c[4][MAXNUMLEN];
    splitter(temp, c);
    printf(c[0]);
    printf(c[1]);
    printf(c[2]);
    printf(c[3]);
}
```

I am encountering a segmentation fault in the line

```
splitted[next_free][i] = *(str+i);
```

However, *(str+i) should always be accessible as i is never greater than the length of the string.

Comment: The problem could be on the left hand side of the assignment.  Also, don't write `*(str+i)`.  Instead, just write `str[i]` which is equivalent but clearer.

Comment: Also, since `str` is loop-invariant, you should not be calling `strlen(str)` inside the loop (e.g., in the `while` test).  Call it once, outside the loop.

Comment: The problem was indeed on the left hand side. I forgot to add a next_op<MAXNUMLEN condition.

Comment: `printf(c[0]);` ==> `printf("%s", c[0]);` or, to put it all together `printf("%s%s%s%s", c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3])`

Comment: @pgp not only, you have to add `str[next_op] && ` to have `for(next_op; str[next_op] && *(str+next_op) != '+' ...`, **but this is not the only error**. Note also to call _strlen_ in the conditions of the _while_ is expensive for nothing

Comment: What do you mean not the only error? What other errors are there?

Comment: @pgp did you executed your code ?

Comment: I have understood that there are other errors (it only prints one). I am trying to think of the problem in the code.

Comment: @pgp why do you not extract the numbers using _strtol_ or _strtod_ also giving you the position after them ? How do you plan to manage the priorities of the operator ? Do you plan to manage ( ) ?

Comment: I was planning to convert to integers after separating. Also, I have fixed the problems as far as I can see.

Comment: @pgp using _strtol_  you separate and get the value at the same time, this is more practical and efficient

Comment: That approach won't work once I add support for brackets, though, will it?

Comment: @pgp your current approach ? currently you just extract items, and yes to place all of them in an array is not the best way, better to use a stack

Comment: Yes, I will do that

Comment: you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510263/infix-to-postfix-conversion-and-evaluation-including-whitespaces-and-double-quotor and also search on S.O. about "infix [c]" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next_op-for never ends when str does not end in an operator. So the i-loop goes to infinity and over the end of str.

```
        ;
```

Comment: this is true but this is not enough to remove all the errors in the code ;-)